# Java/Android: Change from one View (Intent) to another

Tags: java, android, android-intent, view, android-activity

Well, I was watching this tutorial:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ew_Ajpqwqg#t=5m25s

Here you can see that he writes Intent i = new Intent......

But my app doesn't work like that :/

Here's my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button btnAddCategory, btnViewCategory;
EditText txtCategories;
TextView viewMain, viewAllCategories;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtCategories = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCategories);
    viewMain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewMain);
    btnAddCategory = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddCategory);
    btnViewCategory = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewCategory);
    viewAllCategories = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewAllCategories);

    btnAddCategory.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnViewCategory.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View arg0) {

    switch(arg0.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btnAddCategory: 
        boolean didItWork = true;

        try {           
        Categories entry = new Categories(MainActivity.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(txtCategories.getText().toString());
        entry.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            didItWork = false;
        } finally {
            if (didItWork)
            {
                Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                d.setTitle("New Category Created");
                TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                tv.setText("Success");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
        }
    break;
    case R.id.btnViewCategory:
        Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.SQLVIEW");
        startActivity(i);
    break;
    }
}


}
```

SQLView.Java

```
public class SQLView extends Activity {

protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSatate) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceSatate);
    setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infosFromDb);
    Categories info = new Categories(this);
    info.open();
    String data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    tv.setText(data);
} }
```

Manifest

```
        <activity
        android:name=".SQLView" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SQLVIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    </activity>
```

I've read a thread here, where somebody was having the same problem, so I changed it to:

```
case R.id.btnViewCategory:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SQLView.class);
            startActivity(i);
        break;
```

So, now I don't get any exceptions, but I get an empty view. I can only see the name of my app, but that's it, all the TextViews etc. in the views are gone.

Is there anyone with an idea how to handle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any content in `sqlview.xml`?

Comment: Um, computers kind of care about CASE.

Comment: yeah, there is content in sqlview.xml - it's only a TextView, but it should be enough for the start. @codeMagic

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times we write intents ,we miss some thing ,which takes time
I don't have Solution to your problem but i think its better than finding the missing part by watching the youtube video again and again.
Right Click on Project name for example : for Myandroidprojext

```
   Myandroidprojext->new->other->Android Activity
```

This is the easy way to make new Activity without changing the Manifest Files or doing extrawork.

Comment: Totally did it for me! I don't know what I did wrong, but now it's 100% working lol. Thanks a lot for your help!